# SQLite averaging lot of rows into X averaged value between two desired row

Tags: sql, sqlite, average

I have rows in SQLite, let's say 10.0000 with last row as unix timestamp. I would like to average every value from today 00:00 to 23:59 into X averaged group. If there is 1000 records today and X is 10, then average each 100 value and the result would be 10x averaged 100 records. If x is 20, average each value and result is averaged values 50x. *Those values are from sensors, like temperature and I would like to be able to track what the temperature was today between X and Y hours and so, for each day.*

What would be the best efficient way to do this? I'm using SQLite3 with C++, I could do it in C++ with more queries but I would like to let this to SQLite and fetch the result only if it's possible. Visualization: https://i.ibb.co/grSTgrZ/sqlite.png

Any help appreciated where I should start with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  A db fiddle of some sort might also be helpful.

Comment: There is a visualized description about what I would like to achieve: https://i.ibb.co/grSTgrZ/sqlite.png

My database structure is:
temp            INT     NOT NULL,
time            INT     NOT NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`NTILE()`](https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html#built_in_window_functions) window function to create the groups on which you will aggregate:

```
SELECT AVG(value) avg_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY id) grp
  FROM tablename
)  
GROUP BY grp
```

The number inside the parentheses of `NTILE()` corresponds to the number X in your requirement.
`Id` is the column on which the table should be ordered.
If you have a `date` column then change to:

```
SELECT AVG(value) avg_value
FROM (
  SELECT *, NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY date) grp
  FROM tablename
)  
GROUP BY grp
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=30bb5dea33eafe1a64c39f794ef1e248).

Comment: Thank you very much, this was an enormeus help - I already tried it and it worked :) I'm not an expert with SQL, have to learn it a bit deeper.